# I'm getting an error on line 8 that "V" is undefined, despite defining in line 4. Thoughts?

Tags: python

```
import math 
float(input("C"))
#c="speed of light" in m/s
float(input("V"))
#v="speed of mobile" in m/s
float(input("M"))
#m="mass of mobile" in Kg
1/math.sqrt((1-V/C)^2)==Gam2
print(Gam)
M*V==p
M*V*Gam==q
```

I checked the capitalization of the input float of "V", and they still match up, but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: I suggest redoing a tutorial. Calling `input` doesn't define the variable. You actually need to define it like `V = float(...)`. The argument to `input ` only specifies the _prompt_ that is shown to the user

Answer (score 1):

I took the problem you had:

```
import math 
C = float(input("C"))
#c="speed of light" in m/s
V = float(input("V"))
#v="speed of mobile" in m/s
M = float(input("M"))
#m="mass of mobile" in Kg
Gam = 1 / math.sqrt(math.pow(1 - V / C, 2))
print(Gam)
p = M * V
q = M * V * Gam
```

had to define all by a variable and they should be good to go. I ran it through with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You simply *didn't assign the result of user inputs into variables.*
(In other words, you *threw away* user's inputs as something not interesting for you.)

So, instead of these 3 commands, where C, V, and M are **not** variables, but arbitrary texts:

```
float(input("C"))
float(input("V"))
float(input("M"))
```

use

```
C = float(input("Please enter the speed of light  in m/s: "))
V = float(input("Please enter the speed of mobile in m/s: "))
M = float(input("Please enter the mass  of mobile in kg:  "))
```

---

Moreover, if you mean the speed of light in **vacuum**, there is need to ask for it, so the first of the previous 3 commands replace simply with

```
C = 299792458
```

or – if you have Python 3.6+ – with a little nicer expression of such a long number:

```
C = 299_792_458
```